# React reload .env variables after Changing them

Tags: reactjs, environment-variables

in my react app I have a .env file and every time I change them I can't see the change until I stop and npm start again is there a faster why to do it?

Comment: Ref: https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/870#issuecomment-285600286

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Environment variables are passed to process (npm start), so those are stable for 1 process. So that's why you need to kill process and start again, cause variables are already passed and there is no way to hot reload.

Answer (score 1):

I know it is already "solved", but there is actually a better way now: use NextJS.

NextJS 12.3 reloads the app automatically when .env is changed: https://nextjs.org/blog/next-12-3#improved-fast-refresh